# Apple iOS6 Maps - Destination Address > Business name showing instead of lat/long

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

I have an app that bumps the user out to Apple's maps to get directions to a business location, and I'm passing lat/long.  Pretty simple, the URL I'm using is the following:

http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=lat,long

This of course works fine, but the client doesn't like the lat/long showing when the user gets to the maps, since it doesn't look very 'user friendly'.  They would prefer the business name (which we have available) to actually show there.  I informed them that this wouldn't work if we just passed in the business name alone, since Apple's maps may not know about that particular business' location.

However, they wanted to know if it was possible to somehow have it still show the business name in the destination-address, alongside the lat/long.  Something like the following:  "(Business Name) lat,long", where the business name is ultimately ignored and lat/long used.  I've played around with this a bit with no luck.

Looking at Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html), I don't see of an obvious way of accomplishing this.  Is this even possible?  No worries if not, but just wanted to get some feedback.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing an app, you could use `MKMapItem` instead of using the link URL method. With one of these, you can add a bunch of extra information, such as the business name and phone number, as well as the latitude/longitude. Then, you can open one in the Maps app by calling `openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:` on it.

Comment: Yep I think you're correct, this may be our only option here.  Thanks for taking the time to offer a solution on this!